# Implement proof environment as normal paragraph, without list

Tags: amsmath, lists, wrapfigure

I am formatting a math book from another author that uses a lot of figures inside paragraphs, like those produced by `wrapfigure` environment. I am getting a lot of trouble because `proof` and other theorem like environments are implemented by means of lists, and lists interact badly with `wrapfigure`.

I tried packages `wrapfig`, `cutwin` and `insbox.tex`. The last one was promissing, works inside usual `proof` for first wrapped figure, but fails from the second and so on, I suspect that it is because of its “restoration” after it finishes with the figure:

```
\def\@restore@{%
    \global\@wherebottom = 0cm
    \global\@byframefalse
    \global\everypar = {}%
    \global\let \par = \endgraf
    \global\parshape = 1 0cm \hsize
}
```

So I decided to avoid list environments and stick with `wrapfigure` or `insbox`.

From `amsbook.cls` we have the following definition for `proof` environment:

```
\newenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \itemindent\normalparindent
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \scshape
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
```

(You can see `\trivlist` and `\endtrivlist` in the definition.)

I have made my version without lists, that **seams** to be OK. Even `\qedhere` inside math is working. Wrapped figures are all happy.

```
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \vspace{6\p@\@plus6\p@}%
  \noindent
    \textit{#1\@addpunct{.}}\enskip\ignorespaces
  }{%
    \popQED
    \vspace{6\p@\@plus6\p@}\@endpefalse
  }
```

But there must be a reason AMS and others implement these environments as lists that I don't know, but would like to know, and if you know, please share this knoledge :-)  I suspect it could be better spacing before and after the environment.

My question is: how to have a proof environment as good as the one from AMSmath, good looking, good spacing, but without list environments? Am I missing something in my definition of proof?

Edit: I add here a MWE to illustrate.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,amsthm}
\input{insbox}

% my version of proof, here as myproof
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{myproof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \vspace{6\p@\@plus6\p@}%
  \noindent
    \textit{#1\@addpunct{.}}\enskip\ignorespaces
  }{%
    \popQED
    \vspace{6\p@\@plus6\p@}\@endpefalse
  }
\makeatother
  
\begin{document}

\InsertBoxR{0}{\rule{1cm}{1cm}}
\begin{proof}
  \lipsum[1][1-7]

  \InsertBoxR{0}{\rule{1cm}{1cm}}
  \lipsum[1][1-7]
\end{proof}

\lipsum[1][1-7]

\InsertBoxR{0}{\rule{1cm}{1cm}}
\begin{myproof}[My proof]
  \lipsum[1][1-7]

  \InsertBoxR{0}{\rule{1cm}{1cm}}[-1]
  \lipsum[1][1-7]
\end{myproof}

\end{document}
```

Result below: fisrt black square is over text, others are OK.

[image: first black square is over text]

Comment: Could you post a short example reproducing the behaviour you describe with   `insbox`?

Comment: @Bernard, I cold not make a simple example reproducing what I said about `insbox`. I will investigate be behavior I observed in a long text I am formatting: a \InsertBoxR was OK, and when I inserted another _before_, what was OK stop work, In the MWE above I could not reproduce this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When AMS created the three document classes `amsart`, `amsbook` and `amsproc`, there was a strongly held philosophy that they should be as close to the basic LaTeX classes `article`, `book` and `proc`, so that it would be possible for an author to prepare a document using one of those, and simply change the `\documentclass` line to apply the AMS style.  This has proved to be a sound decision for the most part.

The "basic" theorem support in `article`, etc., was based on the list structure, so that was essentially copied for the AMS classes, of which `amsthm` is an integral part.  This was a big mistake, but it wasn't realized until it was too late, and the AMS classes were already in quite extensive use.  (In fact, it's my opinion that considering almost everything to be a list is a serious design misfeature in LateX, one that has never been properly reconsidered, and now it's too late.)

I know that it is on the list of modifications "to be considered" (also known locally as the "bugs and requests list") to get rid of the list restriction -- it only causes problems -- but when or if it might happen is unknown to me.  (I no longer have access to that list, but guess that this request was first made in the last century, i.e., pre-2000.)

By the way, `amsmath` is only peripherally related to the `proof` environment.  `amsmath` and `amsthm` work together, but `proof` is defined in `amsthm`, not `amsmath`.

Sorry that this answers only half your question.